# How to open Apple Maps directly from app?

Tags: swift, apple-maps

Im trying to open apple maps directly from app with this code

```
let url =  "http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=\(latString),\(longString)"             
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "\(url)")!,options: [:],
completionHandler: nil)
```

But it opens '**SAFARI**' first, then moves to apple maps.The problem is that, from maps i cant go back to my app. The top back button only goes back to safari.

Is there a way to open apple maps directly? Or do i have to use google maps for that?

**Edit** : The answer is correct but here is the better one

```
let mapsURL = URL(string: "maps://?saddr=\(latStringS),\(longStringS)&daddr=\(latStringD),\(longStringD)")!

this will show direction to destination from starting location
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem/1452207-openmaps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## General Solution

You should pass app's deeplink as the URL to open them directly. For `Maps` this is the URL you are looking for:

```
let mapsURL = URL(string: "maps://q?\(latString),\(longString)")!
```

---

## Specific Function

Also, there is a Specific function for Maps and that is:

```
class func openMaps(with mapItems: [MKMapItem], launchOptions: [String : Any]? = nil) -> Bool
```

You can find out more about this in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem/1452207-openmaps)

---

## Specific Framework

Also, You can use my framework for this that. supports AppleMaps, GoogleMaps, Waze and Maps.Me.

**[You can get it from here](https://github.com/Chenzook/LocationNavigator)**